# How to call Gmail Api from chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, authorization, google-oauth, gmail-api

I am getting following error while requesting Gmail api :
error
:
code
:
401
errors
:
Array(1)
0
:
domain
:
"global"
location
:
"Authorization"
locationType
:
"header"
message
:
"Invalid Credentials"
reason
:
"authError"
[[Prototype]]
:
Object
length
:
1
[[Prototype]]
:
Array(0)
message
:
"Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See [https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project."](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.%22)
status
:
"UNAUTHENTICATED"
background.js

```
 chrome.identity.getAuthToken().then(token => { 
console.log(token);

fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/labels', {
```

method: 'POST',
headers: {
'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
},
body: JSON.stringify({
labelListVisibility: 'labelShow',
messageListVisibility: 'show',
name: 'labelName'
})
}).then(response => response.json())`enter code here`
.then(data => console.log(data))
.catch(error => console.error(error));

});

Comment: What's your `host_permissions` in manifest.json?

Comment: @wOxxOm followings are my host permissions :  "host_permissions": [
    "https://mail.google.com/"
  ],

Comment: You need to add `https://www.googleapis.com/`

Comment: @wOxxOm still got the same error

Comment: Don't forget to reload the extension on chrome://extensions page.

Comment: I reload it every time i make changes but errror continues

Comment: if you found any solution, could you update it here.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try adding

```
"oauth2": {
    "client_id": "<YOUR_CLIENT_ID>.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "scopes": [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify",
      "https://mail.google.com/"
    ]
  },
```

Having the [www.googleapis.com](http://www.googleapis.com) in the "scopes" worked for me.

Also, take a look at the match patterns, I've been working with a Gmail extension and my "matches" are *://mail.google.com/*

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/match_patterns/

Comment: I have same setup as you mentioned but getting the error